# Match exact string inside square brackets - printed in colours

Tags: shell, awk

I have a text file similar to the below image.
[image]

I want to fetch lines that match with the second column. For example, lines matching [403] should print only `https://www.tst.example.com`

The awk command given below gave me a blank output.
`awk '$2 == "[403]"' file.txt`

Later I checked the text file using nano editor and verified the content in the second column. The text inside the brackets has the color codes.

```sh
https://www.test.example.com [^[[0;31m503^[[0m]
https://www.tst.example.com [^[[0;31m403^[[0m]
https://www.tt.example.com [^[[0;31m302^[[0m]
```

I also tried the `awk '$2 == "[^[[0;31m503^[[0m]"' file.txt` which gave a blank output.

How to do this, with grep or awk ?

Comment: Why did you save output with color codes into a file in the first place?

Comment: What do you mean by *"lines that match with the second column"*. Are you interested in lines which contain 403 error in them - i.e. those matching "[403]"?

Comment: @oguzismail that's an ouput file from another script

Comment: @costaparas - Yes that's exactly what I want

Comment: @JoelDeleep since those color codes are causing you problems why not just remove them? From your posted sample input it looks like `awk 'match($2,/[0-9]{3}/){$2="["substr($2,1,3)"]"}1'` or `sed 's/\(.* \).*\([0-9]\{3\}\).*/\1[\2]/'` is all you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'index($2, "403") {print $1}' file.txt
```

The above code should do what you want with your example input.

I'd have tried to remove the color codes from the file using some tool. Or instruct the program which generated that output to not produce colored output.

Comment: That was the compact solution.
This was done initially and generating the file again will take more time, but will disable colours next time.

Comment: @Joel Just in case, nano shows `\033` as `^[[`; so `awk '$2 == "[\0330;31m503\0330m]" { print $1 }' file` will also work if you need to test the field in its entirety for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `awk '$2 == "[^[[0;31m503^[[0m]"' file.txt` and it does give me the right output (`https://www.test.example.com [^[[0;31m503^[[0m]`), maybe there is something else you did ?

Simpler is also `grep -n 503 file.txt` if your file is short and your links doesn't contain numbers.

There is also `grep -nF "[^[[0;31m503^[[0m]" file.txt` with the "n" to display line numbers and the "F" for ignoring special characters.